# What does a strain gauge amplifier do?

Tags: strain-gage

I was at a placement for the last few weeks, and a lot of people were talking about a strain gauge amplifier. It was a box (the box was about 10cm x 8cm, 3D printed) although I didn't get to open it up. I know that strain gauges are thin wires that create a difference in resistance when a force is applied, so does a strain gauge just convert it into a voltage value? How does it actually work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, a strain gauge amplifier amplifies the small signal from a strain gauge.

A strain gauge is a resistive material that changes resistance when deformed as a result of applied force.  This change in resistance is usually measured using a Wheatstone bridge.  Note that, depending on the design of the strain gauge, one or two or all four arms of the Wheatstone bridge are part of the gauge.  The advantage of the bridge is that its balanced configuration helps to cancel out temperature induced resistance changes of the strain gauge.  The better strain gauges use four resistive elements in the bridge configuration.

The Wheatstone bridge converts the resistance changes of the strain gauge into a voltage.  This voltage is usually floating at half the bridge excitation voltage and is very small (microvolts to millivolts) compared to the excitation voltage.  A differential amplifier is used to amplify and convert it into a larger voltage, suitable for displaying on a meter or digitizing.  This diff amp can have either a single-ended or differential output, depending on the A/D converter you are using.

Comment: Just to add, not all stain gages are resistive.  Some are piezo, and use charge amplifiers.  Others may be capacitive and use AC Wheatstone bridges or oscillator configs.

Answer (score 0):

A strain gauge amp obviously amplifies the strain gauge signal.
I'm pretty sure a strain gauge gives some small resistance change signal due to the differential "volume" change in the resistive film as it is bent.  I'd start by checking the wikipedia page?  You should at least provide a link to the page with your question.  You need to show that you've done some work on your question.